# xpages using search give me query Not understandable [on Web pages] and notes Client

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

Some weird Error happens on Customer server side. The error it give is **Query not understandable** every times i accessing that page. While in my own server testing database. Everything fine.

I think is related with ft index of the database but i not sure which part of it is wrong.

[image]
[image]

Script is :

```
revname = @Name('[CN]', @UserName())
var dep=[];

var vw:NotesView = database.getView("Reviewer sort by Name");
var dc : NotesDocumentCollection = vw.getAllDocumentsByKey(revname,true)

var doc:NotesDocument = dc.getFirstDocument()
var tmpDoc:NotesDocument
while (doc != null) {
    tmpDoc = dc.getNextDocument();
    dep.push(doc.getItemValueString("dept"))
    doc.recycle();
    doc = tmpDoc;
}

return "[dep]=" + dep
```

result should return on search is **[dep]=Information Technology (I.T.)**

The error list

```
com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: Notes error: Query is not understandable
    com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.viewnavigator.AbstractViewCollectionNavigator.readEntries(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoViewEntryArray.readEntries(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoViewDataContainer.readViewEntries(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoViewDataContainer.getRowCount(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoViewDataModel.getRowCount(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.model.TabularDataModel.isRowAvailable(Unknown Source)
    javax.faces.component.UIData.isRowAvailable(Unknown Source)
    javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndex(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataEx.setRowIndex(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.DataTableRendererEx.encodeTabularDataModelRows(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.DataTableRendererEx.encodeTabularDataModelChildren(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.DataTableRendererEx.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.ViewPanelRenderer.encodeBegin(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeBegin(Unknown Source)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(Unknown Source)
    javax.faces.component.UIData.encodeBegin(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataEx.encodeBegin(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewPanel.encodeBegin(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderChildren(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderChildren(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderChildren(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderChildren(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderChildren(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderChildren(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderChildren(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx._renderView(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.renderView(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.doRender(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl._renderView(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.renderView(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.render(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.access$0(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService$NsfServiceRequest.call(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService$NsfServiceRequest.call(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService$NsfServiceThread.run(Unknown Source)
NotesException: Notes error: Query is not understandable
    lotus.domino.local.View.FTSearchSorted(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.viewnavigator.FTViewNavigatorEx.createCollection(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.viewnavigator.AbstractViewCollectionNavigator.readEntries(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoViewEntryArray.readEntries(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoViewDataContainer.readViewEntries(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoViewDataContainer.getRowCount(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoViewDataModel.getRowCount(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.model.TabularDataModel.isRowAvailable(Unknown Source)
    javax.faces.component.UIData.isRowAvailable(Unknown Source)
    javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndex(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataEx.setRowIndex(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.DataTableRendererEx.encodeTabularDataModelRows(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.DataTableRendererEx.encodeTabularDataModelChildren(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.DataTableRendererEx.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.ViewPanelRenderer.encodeBegin(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeBegin(Unknown Source)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(Unknown Source)
    javax.faces.component.UIData.encodeBegin(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataEx.encodeBegin(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewPanel.encodeBegin(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderChildren(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderChildren(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderChildren(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderChildren(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderChildren(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderChildren(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderChildren(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx._renderView(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.renderView(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.doRender(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl._renderView(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.renderView(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.render(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.access$0(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService$NsfServiceRequest.call(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService$NsfServiceRequest.call(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService$NsfServiceThread.run(Unknown Source
```

computed field :

[image]

1. Reviewer View using **"Desmond Sim Chia Che"** to return value

   dep = Information Technology(I.T.)

   **[This one give Error query not understandable]**
2. Reviewer View using **"Brooke Dept Mgr1"** to return value

   dep = Technical, dep = Project Delivery Unit , dep = Administration

   **[No Error]**

I cant find the different between it

Attached photo for view
[image]
[image]

Comment: You most likely get more than one document in production.  Send the query string to debug to see what it actually is. Wrap the call in Try catch and return info to see what you are dealing with

Comment: i try put  my script on the computed field, result come out  : [dep] = Information Technology(I.T.)

Comment: Sorry stwissel, i not understand how to debug on query string. As i know debug function only allow debug lotus script using [tool]? some update with attachment add on to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't `dep` an array? What do you expect it outputs concatenated with `[dep]=`?

You must build a string according to the FT search syntax. For each value you must repeat `"[dep]=" + doc.getItemValueString(` and concatenate each condition with an `OR` - or `AND` operator (you know your logic). To be on the safer side you should also surround each value after the `=` sign with double quotes, although it's not strictly mandatory... much depends on the value at hand...

e.g.: `[dep]="Technical" OR [dep]="Project Delivery Unit" OR [dep]="Administration"`

Comment: I've learned from inherited applications that values with spaces will often cause problems. A parser can work fine if the value you're testing against is just one word. It can compensate for the query not being constructed semantically correct. But when there are spaces in the value, like `dep = Information Technology(I.T.)`, it's best to be semantically correct and test the string field against a string value, and string values in code are wrapped in double quotes (although LS is coded syntactically to allow variants like { and |).

Comment: If you're dealing with field values that as a developer you don't have control of, it may also be worth escaping potential double quotes within the values passed.

Comment: Thanks Paul. add double quote on search string will solve it.